# Does it make any sense to use `nom` to process custom enum types?

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I am attempting to implement a parser for a simple query language. The goal is to generate `operations` from the text and then evaluate them before passing them up the tree. If I understand correctly, I'll have to implement some of the nom traits (`InputLength`, `InputTake`, `Slice`).

Part way through implementing the `InputTake` trait, I realize that I'm expected to return subslices of the enums which represent my query operations where a split may be made part way through an identifier. For example, I may parse an identifier `name_of_var` and this `take_split()` method could produce 2 slices which doesn't make sense to me.

What should I be doing here? I don't like the idea of slicing a bool/number since they only make sense as a whole.

What do you think about returning `None` in the case where I consider a byte slice invalid?

Comment: what is your input type? Is it not `&str`? Or do you separate the text in a list of tokens that you then want to process with nom?

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I assumed that the output type of one parser was the input of a parent parser.

What really happens is that all parsers can expect the same input type and return whatever they like. The generated object (which is an AST) is returned and manipulated in the end.

I literally figured that out 5 mins after posting this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you say you figured out the problem, but didn't post the solution as an answer, rather you posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth...

I assumed that the output type of one parser was the input of a parent parser. What really happens is that all parsers can expect the same input type and return whatever they like. The generated object (which is an AST) is returned and manipulated in the end.